As the robot moves, the laser scan drifts and the positioning is not accurate,laser not match map
I am using ROS melodic. I use cartograther for positioning and lidar navigation. The vehicle body is a two-wheel differential model. During actual operation, it is found that the lidarlaser of the robot will drift and does not match the map.
I am not sure which aspect of the problem this is, whether it is cartograther positioning or odometer error?
This is the rosbag that I uploaded to Google Drive.
Second Edit:
Through calibration of motion, I found that the odometer was inaccurate. When I required to run 1 meter, it actually ran 1.1 meters, with an extra 10 cm.
Are there any good methods to improve this problem?


